# Extract all the external links that have a CAD file

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

Is there any way to extract all the external links files that have a CAD file?

Any library in c# or another programming language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'external links'
Do You mean Block - ExternalReference (XRef) ? or AcDbEntity::Hyperlinks property ?

Comment: The first, external references. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ad hoc sample would be:

```
ObjectIdCollection XRefs = new ObjectIdCollection();

Database db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    BlockTable blocks = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead, false) as BlockTable;
    foreach (ObjectId blockId in blocks)
    {
        BlockTableRecord bx = tr.GetObject(blockId, OpenMode.ForRead, false) as BlockTableRecord;
        if (bx.IsFromExternalReference)
        {
            ObjectIdCollection references = bx.GetBlockReferenceIds(true, true);
            foreach (ObjectId ref in references)
            XRefs.Add (ref)
        }
    }
    tr.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Hi, to compile these code, I guess that I have to install in the c# project with nuget the AutoCAD.NET. But my project is in 4.5 version. I have to find what version match. Where is the original CAD file opened?

Comment: This code can be compiled in project based on ObjectARX. so the output is dll file which can be loaded to AutoCAD by _netload command in AutoCAD. nuget package is not necessary. My project is based on .Net Framework 4. with referenced ARX sdk libraries. Drawing is opened in AutoCAD, to be honest in my case it's ZWCAD, but this should be no difference.